# Scales of Banach Spaces: Literature?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

Does someone know a nice reference for:
$$E^{-s'}\hookrightarrow E^{-s}\hookrightarrow E^0=E\hookrightarrow E^s\hookrightarrow E^{s'}\quad(s\leq s')$$
*(I need a more abstract view; less focus on PDE.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ł. Dawidowski, *Scales of Banach spaces, theory of interpolation and their applications*, Wydawnictwo UŚ, Katowice, 2012.

List of contents to be found [here](https://wydawnictwo.us.edu.pl/sites/wydawnictwo.us.edu.pl/files/scales_of_banach_-_czw_contents_preface_streszczenie_reziume_st.pdf).